# Bootstrap modal not showing (taken from the official website) using Django

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-modal

I have the following HTML code in Django template. I used the example from Boostrap website to create a button that shows a modal ,however, when I press the button, nothing happens. I'm not sure why nothing happens and also no error shows in the console.
My 'static' folder contains:
`bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.css.map`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {% load static %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="{% static "img/logo.png" %}" style='max-width:100px'></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'admin:logout' %}?next=/" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Instances</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        New Instance
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Instance</button>

  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          This is a test!
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which Bootstrap version are you using? Make sure to also include the Bootstrap JS because the Bootstrap modal is built using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: when you do frontend developing and errors come up check the browser console. usually they will give you a hint where the error is and you have something to post here so we get more ifnos as well....

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that nothing wrong with your modal code. But you missed to provide all .js files that it needs. Remember all data- are JavaScript functions. Below is the code I fixed for you and it all works perfectly. I installed BS, jQuery and popper.js in the work folder so I call all needed files from node_modules. You need to enter corresponding links if you refer to online cdn.

If my answer works, please tick it as final answer and upvote it so other people with same problem will get help too. Cheers

ps: just come back. In case you want to install as what I did => download install node.js => then enter these commands in cmd

npm install bootstrap --save
npm install jquery popper.js --save

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {% load static %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
     
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'admin:logout' %}?next=/" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Instances</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        New Instance
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Instance</button>

  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          This is a test!
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```